# Last weekday from specific date in php

Tags: php, date

I am looking for the best way to get the last weekday from a particular date. The example I am using is what was the last workday before Christmas eve (24th Dec).

unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', strtotime('last weekday before 24th December 2012'));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just remove `before` and your example will work fine (as of PHP 5.2.0). The absolute date part (`24th December 2012`) is processed first, followed by the relative part (`last weekday`), as per the [relative formats documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

**Original**

```
last weekday before 24th December 2012
```

**Correct**

```
last weekday 24th December 2012
```

---

Per the other answers, `previous` and `last` when used as in the question behave in the exact same way; meaning the immediately preceding occurrence of *something* (in this case, a weekday). `last` does have another special meaning when used in the style of `last dayname of`, which is not being used in the question.

Reference:

- [Relative Formats manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)
- And in fact each of the [date/time formats pages](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) document the available formats.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', strtotime('24th December 2012 previous weekday'));
```

This will output something like `Friday 21st of December 2012 12:00:00 AM` using `PHP 5.3.19`

Heres another way you could go about this, its not the prettiest thing but it should work:

```
$date = '24th December 2012';
$dateN = intval(date('N', strtotime($date)));

if ($dateN === 1) {
    $prevWeekday = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', strtotime($date . '-3 days'));
} else if ($dateN === 7) {
    $prevWeekday = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', strtotime($date . '-2 day'));
} else {
    $prevWeekday = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', strtotime($date . '-1 day'));
}

echo $prevWeekday;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLastWorkingday(){
  $year_month = date('Y-m');
  $lastDay = date('N', strtotime('last day of '.$year_month));
  $lastDayt = date('t', strtotime('last day of '.$year_month));

  if($lastDay == 6){
    $lastWorkingday = $lastDayt-1;
  }elseif($lastDay == 7){
    $lastWorkingday = $lastDayt-2;
  }else{
    $lastWorkingday = date('t');
  }

  return $lastWorkingday;
}

if( getLastWorkingday() == date('d') ){
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).