# How to get the last weekday of the current month?

Tags: php, date

How can I get the last weekday (Mon-Fri) of the current month in php?

Comment: Was this one too crypric? https://stackoverflow.com/q/38509093/2943403 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/13960133/2943403

Answer (score 0):

Using [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) and [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php).

`strtotime("last weekday October 2021")` will produce the timestamp of the last weekday of **September**. Using that, we just need to add a month to the current date and get the last weekday before that month using strtotime.

```
$nextMonth = strtotime("+1 month");
$dateString = "last weekday " . date("F Y", $nextMonth);
$lastWorkDayOfMonth = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateString));
```

Comment: This does work, but can you explain why `strtotime("last weekday October 2021")` works for **September**? Anyone?

Comment: I suppose "October 2021" get's translated to the first of October. "last weekday" finds the last weekday before the first of October. That equals the last weekday of September.